# Define a function to generate a dictionary

Tags: python

```
def create_dictionary(params)
```

How do I generate a dictionary from a string value which comes
from its parameter named `params`. The dictionary is created with the use of zip function to handle the keys and values which are generated from `params`

How do I make the output of this:

```
print(create_dictionary('name:= Jack ; grade:=3'))
```

To be like this:

```
{'name': 'Jack', 'grade': '3'}
```

Comment: Do you have any control over the incoming format? Because if you can get it in a JSON format there are tools to do this already.  As it is you'll have to write your own parser for your specific input format.

Answer (score 3):

```
def create_dictionary(string1):
  s = string1.split(';')
  dic = {}
  for i in s:
     key, value = i.split(':=')
     dic[key] = value
  return dic
```

Answer (score 0):

If the string's syntax is same all the time, you can split the string accordingly. In this case:

First split them with `;` to separate dictionary values.

Then split rest with `:=` to get the key and the value. You may want to trim the resulting key and value to remove the white spaces around.

**Note:** If data itself contains the `;` or `:=`, this solution will fail.

***Edit***

In addition to the Daniel Paul's answer for removing the white spaces:

```
def create_dictionary(string1):
  s = string1.split(';')
  dic = {}
  for i in s:
     key, value = i.split(':=')
     dic[key.strip()] = value.strip()
  return dic
```

Before: `{'name': ' Jack ', ' grade': '3'}` after `{'name': 'Jack', 'grade': '3'}`

Answer (score 0):

One-liner using python's dict comprehension:

```py
def create_dictionary(string):
    {a.strip():b.strip() for a,b in [i.split(':=') for i in string.split(';')]}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can use the split method and split `:=` or you can follow up my code**

```
def dict_fun(*args):
    dict = {}
    cnt = 0
    count = 0
    while cnt < len(args):
        for i in args[cnt]:
            if i == ':':
                print(count)
                dict[args[cnt][0:count]] = args[cnt].strip().replace(' ','')[count+2:]
                break
            else:
                count += 1
        cnt += 1
        count = 0
    return(dict)
print(dict_fun('name:=Jack', 'grade:=3'))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
{'name': 'Jack', 'grade': '3'}
```

**Now you can give as many argument as many you want inside `dict_fun('name:=jack','grade:=3',etc..)` so as of taking single string now you can give mutiple string argument to the function and it would return you the dict of that string..**